# PostMapping Service Rest with Spring boot error Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not identifying the problem.

**Controller**

```
@RestController("/api")
public class CoordenadaController {

    @Autowired private RepositorioCoordenada repositorioCoordenada;

    @PostMapping("/salvar")
    public void save(String nome, int coordenadaX, int coordenadaY) {
        this.repositorioCoordenada.save(new Coordenada(nome, coordenadaX, coordenadaY));
        System.out.println("Salvou.....");
    }
}
```

**PostMan Client**

**url** `localhost:8080/api/salvar?nome=Igreja&coordenadaX=10&coordenadaY=20`

**Log Erro PostMan Client**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1493257315171,
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path": "/api/salvar"
}
```

**Log Error Spring**

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
2017-04-26 22:41:55.168  WARN 8388 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

If you remove / api in @RestController the method annotated with @Post works

```
localhost:8080/salvar?nome=Igreja&coordenadaX=10&coordenadaY=20
```

Comment: Don't you need `@RestController @RequestMapping("/api")` at the class level?

Comment: Thank you, it was lack of attention.

Comment: you are trying to do it wrong according to your example, you are doing get. is post you don't send parameters in the query params. so eaither do GETMapping, or fix you your method to have @RequestBody. look here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing POST with GET.
if you want to do POST do the following:

```
@RestController("/api")
public class CoordenadaController {

@Autowired private RepositorioCoordenada repositorioCoordenada;

@PostMapping("/salvar")
public void save(@RequestBody Payload payload) {
    this.repositorioCoordenada.save(new Coordenada(payload.nome, payload.coordenadaX, payload.coordenadaY));
    System.out.println("Salvou.....");
}
```

}

```
public class Payload{
String nome, int coordenadaX, int coordenadaY

//getters & setters
}
```

then use the postmant accordingly: use post method, create a json payload and add it to the Body section

json payload:

```
{
    "nome": "bla bla",
    "coordenadaX": "1",
    "coordenadaY": "2"
}
```

you can check spring tutorial for for further information  : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 1):

you need to set uri path on @RequestMapping after @RestController annotation, by example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/yourpath")
public class YourClass {
  ...
  ...
}
```

So, in your code you set this path in @RestController, that's the reason why postman request works on "/salvar" without /api path, because for spring this path wasn't declared.